# relative xpath php

Tags: php, xpath

I'm parsing html that looks like this:

```
  <table class="linesTbl">
        <tr class="linesHeader">
            <td><h3>EventName</h3></td>
        </tr><tr class="linesColumns">
            <td>Date</td><td class="contestLine">Description</td>
        </tr><tr class="linesAlt1">
            <td>Time</td><td>X1</td><td>Price1</td>
        </tr><tr class="linesAlt1">
            <td>&nbsp;</td><td>X2</td><td>Price2</td></tr>
</table>
```

There are multiple tables like this so I'm trying to loop through them and grab all of the data. I'm not sure how xpath handles queries in php. Currently I'm just trying to extract the EventName from each table.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach ($xpath->query("//table[@class = 'linesTbl']") as $tableNode){

  $headerTag = $xpath->query(".//h3", $tableNode);
  echo $headerTag->nodeValue;

}
```

For the $headerTag query I also tried `query("./tr/td/h3", $tableNode)`. How do I go about doing this relative query?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your xpath expression is relative already:

```
$headerTag = $xpath->query(".//h3", $tableNode);
                            ^       ^^^^^^^^^^
                            |    relative-to node
                       relative path
```

However, this returns a nodelist, not a single node, so if you do:

```
echo $headerTag->item(0)->nodeValue;
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

You can access the element you want, see the output:

```
EventName
```

Comment: probably a *bit* late: what is the **correct** query, so? The code you wrote suggests the original query is not the right one.

Comment: Yeah, a bit late, but the original query most likely was not the issue, but reading the result data from the result object. `query()` returns a [**DOMNodeList**](http://php.net/DOMNodeList), the OP more or less expected it to return a single **DOMElement**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your html is not proper.

Regarding XPATH, you can do this way to target specially to `h3` tag:-

```
/table[@class='linesTbl']/tr[@class='linesHeader']/td/h3
```

Comment: If I only needed the EventName this would work but I need to parse all of the data and keep everything associated with the table it came from.